# How can we version two different git repositories at the same place?

Tags: git, version-control, repository, versioning

How can we version two different git repositories at the same place?

For example, if we have a folder `twoRepositories` and insided of it we have two files `common.txt` and `root.txt` (owned by the root user). How can we version the first file with a common user (and using a remote called, for example, `common`) and the second file (and using another remote called, for example, `root`) independently?

In other words, when we use `git push` with the common user the common.txt(only) file is sent to the `common` remote and when use `git push` as root the `root.txt` foes to the `root`remote.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use two different branches - each with only one of the files in?

Comment: This will not work as I expect. The common user should not be able to switch to the another repository (or as you propose, to the root branch). Another thing is I would like keep both files at the same time (not to have it on different branches). One could be a virtualhost configuration and the another a log, for example.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating two distinct directories - each their own git repositories and symlink  the relevant files into each ?

Comment: The truth is I'm doing this, but I'm wondering with we have a way to put them to live together. Looks like the params available at the [git init](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-init.html) could help. I need to take a look.